# Deployed ModalPopupExtender working in FF and Chrome not IE11

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following page:

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="approval.aspx.cs" Inherits="TimeEntry.approval" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentSubHeader" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="Body" runat="server">

  <%--  <script type="text/javascript">


        function pageLoad() {
            var mpe = $find("MPE");
            mpe.add_shown(onShown);

        }
        function onShown() {
            var background = $find("MPE")._backgroundElement;
            background.onclick = function () { $find("MPE").hide(); }
        }
    </script>--%>



    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUser" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlUser_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Joseph" Value="3" Selected="True" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Todd" Value="4" />
            </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPeriod" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPeriod_SelectedIndexChanged" OnDataBound="ddlPeriod_DataBound" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:GridView ID="grdApproval" OnRowDataBound="grdApproval_RowDataBound" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="grdApproval_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="TimesheetHeaderID" DataField="TimesheetHeaderID" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hide" FooterStyle-CssClass="hide" ItemStyle-CssClass="hide" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="EmployeeID" DataField="EmployeeID" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hide" FooterStyle-CssClass="hide" ItemStyle-CssClass="hide" />

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridHeader" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridItem">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkViewDetail" runat="server" OnClick="grdApproval_SelectedIndexChanged">View Detail</asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Employee" DataField="EmpName" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridHeader" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridItem" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Approval Status" DataField="ApprovalStatusID" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridHeader" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridItem" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Cost Code" DataField="CostCodeID" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridHeader" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridItem" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="REG TIME" DataField="REGTime" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridHeader" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridItem" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="PTO" DataField="PTO" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridHeader" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridItem" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridHeader" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridItem">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnApprove" runat="server" OnClick="grdApproval_SelectedIndexChanged">Approve</asp:LinkButton>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnReject" runat="server" OnClick="grdApproval_SelectedIndexChanged">Reject</asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:Button ID="btnApproveAll" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnApproveAll_Click" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnfake" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="hide" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnfake2" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="hide" />
            <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="PopUp" BehaviorID="MPE" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlDetails" TargetControlID="btnfake" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"></ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlDetails" CssClass="modalPopup">
                <div>
                    <asp:GridView ID="grdTimecardDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Pay Type" DataField="PayTypeDescription" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridHeader" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridItem" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="BusinessUnit" DataField="BusinessUnitID" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridHeader" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridItem" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="CostCode" DataField="CostCodeID" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridHeader" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridItem" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Workorder" DataField="WorkorderID" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridHeader" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridItem" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="SUN" DataField="Day1" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridHeader" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridItem" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="MON" DataField="Day2" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridHeader" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridItem" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="TUE" DataField="Day3" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridHeader" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridItem" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="WED" DataField="Day4" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridHeader" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridItem" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="THU" DataField="Day5" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridHeader" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridItem" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="FRI" DataField="Day6" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridHeader" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridItem" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="SAT" DataField="Day7" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridHeader" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridItem" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Total" DataField="TotalHours" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridHeader" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridItem" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>

            <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="PopUpReject" PopupControlID="pnlReject" CancelControlID="btnCancel" TargetControlID="btnFake2" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"  runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlReject" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup">
                <div>
                    Reject Reason
                </div>
                <div>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtReject" runat="server"  TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="6" Height="148px" Width="381px"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <asp:Button ID="btnOK" runat="server" Text="Reject" OnClick="btnOK_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
            </asp:Panel>

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

</asp:Content>
```

In Visual Studio, everything works fine in all browsers.  When deployed to IIS 8.5, the page works perfectly in FireFox and Chrome, not IE11 which is a requirement.

When I run it in IE debug it throws two errors:

1. SCRIPT87: Invalid Arguement - File ScriptResource.axd, (1,3330)
2. Unable to set property actControlType of undefined or null reference - File ScriptResource.axd, (1,3330)

If any more info would help, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the site to the user's trusted sites fixed the issue.